# Get HTTP GET response in Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am calling the REST GET method and trying to display the result of the REST call in Visualforce page. I developed the code so far but facing small error.

```
Unknown property 'ApexRestController.cases'
```

**It would be better to display result on page load only. How ?**

When I tried using Postman I got the following response which I want to show to client using Visualforce page.

```
{"attributes":{"type":"Case","url":"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Case/5007F000000qqvCQAQ"},
"CaseNumber":"00001047",
"Subject":"Bigfoot Sighting!",
"Status":"Working",
"Priority":"Medium",
"Id":"5007F000000qqvCQAQ"}
```

The code I developed so far:

**CaseDetails**

```
public class CaseDetails {
    public String CaseNumber {get; set;}
    public String Subject {get; set;}
    public String Status {get; set;}
    public String Priority {get; set;}
    public String Id {get; set;}
}
```

**ApexRestVFPage**

```
<apex:page controller="ApexRestController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:commandButton reRender="table1" value="Get Case Details" action="{!getCaseDetailsById}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock id="table1">
            <b>Output Contact Details </b>
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="c">
                <apex:column headerValue="CaseNumber" value="{!c.CaseNumber}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Subject" value="{!c.Subject}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Status" value="{!c.Status}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**ApexRestController**

```
public class ApexRestController {
    public static List<CaseDetails> cases {get; set;}


    public static String getAccessToken(){
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token');

        String CLIENT_ID = 'XXXXX';
        String CLIENT_SECRET = 'XXX';
        String USERNAME = 'XXX';
        String PASSWORD = 'XX';

        req.setBody('grant_type=password' + '&client_id='+CLIENT_ID + 
            '&client_secret='+CLIENT_SECRET + '&username='+USERNAME + '&password='+PASSWORD);

        Http http = new Http();
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

        String access_token = res.getBody();
        List<String> access_tokenList = new List<String>();
        access_tokenList  = access_token.split(',',-1);
        system.debug(access_tokenList[0]);
        access_tokenList  = access_tokenlist[0].split(':',-1);
        system.debug(access_tokenList[1]);
        String tokennew = access_tokenList[1].replace('"','');
        system.debug(tokennew);
        return tokennew;
    } 

    public static CaseDetails getCaseDetailsById(){
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Cases/XXXXX');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+getAccessToken());

        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        System.debug(res.getBody());

        cases = (List<CaseDetails>) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), List<CaseDetails>.class);
        return cases[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: See the answer in your other question (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174388/how-to-deserialized-json-response-in-apex). Based on your response string you should be using `(CaseDetails)` instead of `(List<CaseDetails>)` as your response is currently NOT a list

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you have declared the variable as `static`

```
public static List<CaseDetails> cases {get; set;}
```

And you are trying to access that from

`<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="c">`

That's the reason it is giving `Unknown property 'ApexRestController.cases'` error.

*Correct usage*

```
public List<CaseDetails> cases {get; set;}
```

Comment: static works since getCaseDetailsById() is static, now I face issue in displaying the results !

Comment: @SantanuBoral Can you please answer to this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/194629/vf-page-to-get-the-data-posted-by-external-webservice

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are not serialized (as if you'd used the "transient" keyword), meaning they will be "lost" between each trip back to the server. I would recommend removing all of the static keywords in your code. None of them are necessary for your code to function.