# How to deserialized JSON response in Apex?

Tags: apex

How we can deserialized below response using Apex?

```
{"attributes":{"type":"Case","url":"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Case/XXXXXXX"},
"CaseNumber":"XXX",
"Subject":"My Testing",
"Status":"Working",
"Priority":"Medium",
"Id":"XXX"}
```

I used something like below gave me error:

```
public class CaseDetails {
    public String CaseNumber {get; set;}
    public String Subject {get; set;}
    public String Status {get; set;}
    public String Priority {get; set;}
    public String Id {get; set;}
    public List<Attributes> attributes{get;set;}

    public class Attributes{
        public String type {get;set;}
        public String url {get;set;}
    }
}
```

The error I am getting

```
FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set
FATAL_ERROR Class.ApexRestController.getCaseDetailsById: line 44, column 1
```

**My Controller logic**

```
public List<CaseDetails> cases {get; set;}
cases = (List<CaseDetails>) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), List<CaseDetails>.class);
```

Comment: Are you sure about the data you are getting as `JSON` is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ashwani's answer is the way to go but....

To answer you question directly, your attributes are not a list, they are an object. Adjust your class as follows:

```
public class CaseDetails {
    public String CaseNumber {get; set;}
    public String Subject {get; set;}
    public String Status {get; set;}
    public String Priority {get; set;}
    public String Id {get; set;}
    public Attributes attributes{get;set;} //not a list, instance of class

    public class Attributes{
        public String type_Z {get;set;} //Reserved to spend with _Z
        public String url {get;set;}
    }
}
```

**Important** You have a reserved keyword in your JSON String - *type*. If there is only one then you can do something like this to deserialize:

```
(CaseDetails) JSON.deserialize(resp.getBody().replace('"type"','"type_Z"'), CaseDetails.class));
```

otherwise it could become unmanageable and you would want to use the parser provided by the JSON2Apex

A really good tool to use when you have JSON string you would like to gt into a class would be [JSON2APEX](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com)

Comment: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set
Error is in expression '{!getCaseDetailsById}' in component <apex:commandButton> in page apexrestvfpage: Class.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1
Class.ApexRestController.getCaseDetailsById: line 44, column 1

Comment: The JSON response is the actual response I am getting, but I see issue while displaying the data?

Comment: @user4567570 then you should ask a new question wth the issue you are facing while displaying the data on the VF page.

Comment: @user4567570 - Updated answer. Your JSON was not a list of objects so the casting was not correct

Comment: Return type of an Apex action method must be a PageReference. Found: core.apexpages.el.adapters.ApexObjectValueELAdapter

Comment: @user4567570 - Again, that is a different issue. If you debug the deserialization you will see it is deserialized properly. The return issue can be found here - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=Return+type+of+an+Apex+action+method+must+be+a+PageReference

Comment: Many Thnx Eric, its working perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like Case object. You can deserialize it by type casting and JSON's deserialize method as below:

```
String caseStr = '{"attributes":{"type":"Case","url":"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Case/XXXXXXX"},'+
'"CaseNumber":"XXX",'+
'"Subject":"My Testing",'+
'"Status":"Working",'+
'"Priority":"Medium",'+
'"Id":"XXX"}';

Case caseObj = (Case)JSON.deserialize(caseStr, Case.class);
```

Another way is refer [JSON2Apex link](https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/json2apex). Paste the given JSON. You would get the constructed class as:

```
//
//Generated by AdminBooster
//

public class CaseDetail{
    public cls_attributes attributes;
    public String CaseNumber;   //XXX
    public String Subject;  //My Testing
    public String Status;   //Working
    public String Priority; //Medium
    public String Id;   //XXX
    class cls_attributes {
        public String type; //Case
        public String url;  ///services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Case/XXXXXXX
    }
    public static CaseDetail parse(String json){
        return (CaseDetail) System.JSON.deserialize(json, CaseDetail.class);
    }

    static testMethod void testParse() {
        String json=        '{"attributes":{"type":"Case","url":"/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Case/XXXXXXX"},'+
        '"CaseNumber":"XXX",'+
        '"Subject":"My Testing",'+
        '"Status":"Working",'+
        '"Priority":"Medium",'+
        '"Id":"XXX"}';
        CaseDetail obj = parse(json);
        System.assert(obj != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I display the data in VF pages?

Answer (score 0):

Basic Sample JSON Deserialization... 
Sample JSON Response

```
{
"access_token":"XYZ...",
"tokenType":"BearerToken",
"issuedAt":"1505752810855",
"expiresIn":"35999",
"clientID":"XYZ!@#$$$$$",
"org":"abccorp"
}
```

Controller

```
public class PBAuthRequestBean {
       public String access_token;
       public String tokenType;
       public String issuedAt;
       public String expiresIn;
       public String clientID;
       public String org;


}
```

// Easiest way would be https://www.adminbooster.com/tool/json2apex or http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ for getting the apex

sample Deserialization which works for most of the JSON s

---

```
PBAuthRequestBean responseBean=new PBAuthRequestBean ();
    responseBean= (PBAuthRequestBean )JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(),PBAuthRequestBean.class);
    system.debug('$$$$ResponseBean$$$$'+responseBean.access_token);
```

similar way you can get responseBean.tokenType and others ...

Hope this helps for folks with learning how to serialize ..