# How to replace _id with id in a JSON response using REST API?

Tags: apex, callout, rest, httprequest, queueable-apex

I am making a GET callout to the URL: https://th-superbadge-apex.herokuapp.com/equipment?_ga=2.245262661.1986105727.1612691455-984520333.1610882684. In the URL, the `id` field starts with `_id` which I cant use because I will get compile time error. How do I convert it to `id` and use it in my code?

```
public with sharing class WarehouseCalloutService implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{

      private static final String WAREHOUSE_URL = 'https://th-superbadge-apex.herokuapp.com/equipment?_ga=2.245262661.1986105727.1612691455-984520333.1610882684';
        
            public Integer maintenanceperiod{get;set;}
            public String name{get;set;}
            public Integer lifespan{get;set;}
            public Integer quantity{get;set;}
            public Integer cost{get;set;}
            public Boolean replacement{get;set;}
            public String sku{get;set;}
            public String  id{get;set;}
        
        public void execute(QueueableContext qc) {
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint(WAREHOUSE_URL);
            request.setMethod('GET');
            HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
            
            
            // If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
               List<Object> results = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
                system.debug(results);
     
            }
        }}
```

Comment: Have you tried casting to String as you iterate over the `List<Object> results`? Im not sure why you would get a compile error, it might be more helpful for you to include the code which caused a compile error along with the error message itself.

Comment: When I declare public string _id I get a compile error. Underscore is not allowed as the first character. Sorry, I’m not in front of my computer now.

Answer (score 1):

Variable naming is fine here. It seems you are confused with how you would extract the `_id` value from the deserialized response. Here is a simple example of outputting each Id found in the deserialized response through a `System.debug()`.

```
....

// If the request is successful, parse the JSON response.
if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    // Deserialize the JSON string into collections of primitive data types.
    List<Object> results = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
    
    for (Object result : results) {
        Map<String, Object> resultMap = (Map<String, Object>) result;
        System.debug('Id: ' + (String) resultMap.get('_id'));
    }
}

....
```

The idea would then be that you safely construct the data structures you need in memory or in the database as you loop through each `result`.

Comment: Thank you. What’s the purpose of the casting of map in the 2nd line after for loop? Can you explain that line please?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when solving Apex Specialist superbadge(when calling https://th-superbadge-apex.herokuapp.com/equipment).
I found the solution in the answer for different(not related to this question) issue: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/174391

It is possible to call replace on the response body to change '_id' to 'id'. For example:

```
(List<cEquipment>.class)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody().replace('"_id"','"id"'),List<cEquipment>.class)
```

cEquipment declared as

```
public class cEquipment {
  public String id {get; set;}
  /* other fields
  ... 
  */
}
```